# Error loading TensorFlow graph with C API

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use the TensorFlow C API to load and execute a graph.  It keeps failing and I can't figure out why.

I first use this Python script to create a very simple graph and save it to a file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, 3], name='input')
    output = tf.reduce_sum(input**2, name='output')
tf.train.write_graph(graph, '.', 'test.pbtxt')
```

Then I use this C++ code to load it in.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <c_api.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream graphFile("test.pbtxt");
    string graphText((istreambuf_iterator<char>(graphFile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    TF_Buffer* buffer = TF_NewBufferFromString(graphText.c_str(), graphText.size());
    TF_Graph* graph = TF_NewGraph();
    TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* importOptions = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();
    TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
    TF_GraphImportGraphDef(graph, buffer, importOptions, status);
    cout<<TF_GetCode(status)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The status code it prints is 3, or `TF_INVALID_ARGUMENT`.  Which argument is invalid and why?  I verified the file contents are loaded correctly into `graphText`, and all the other arguments are trivial.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should write the Graph with `as_graph_def()`, in your case:

```py
with open('test.pb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(graph.as_graph_def().SerializeToString())
```

Apart from it, I recommend you not to use the C API directly as it is error prone with memory leaks. Instead I have tried your code using [cppflow](https://github.com/serizba/cppflow), a C++ wrapper, and it works like a charm. I have used the following code:

```cpp
# Load model    
Model model("../test.pb");

# Declare tensors by name
auto input = new Tensor(model, "input");
auto output  = new Tensor(model, "output");

# Feed data
std::vector<float> data(30, 1);
input->set_data(data);

# Run and show
model.run(input, output);
std::cout << output->get_data<float>()[0] << std::endl;
```